# Cannot create sqlite database on device

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm new to android and created my first app which uses an embeded sqlite databse. I've filled the database and the app works fine on android studio emulator but when I try to access it on my mobile device, the app is empty.

I have pulled `myapp.db` and then pushed it to the device:

```
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554  push /home/me/Desktop/myapp2/myapp.db  /data/data/com.myappshop.myapp/databases/myapp.db
```

So I can see these files using adb shell:

```
root@generic_x86_64:/data/data/com.myappshop.myapp/databases # ls -al
-rw-rw---- u0_a72   u0_a72      16384 2016-05-20 20:04 dictionary.db
-rw------- u0_a72   u0_a72       8720 2016-05-20 20:04 dictionary.db-journal
-rw-rw-rw- root     root       253952 2016-05-26 01:27 myapp.db
-rw------- u0_a72   u0_a72       8720 2016-05-23 00:53 myapp.db-journal
-rw-rw---- u0_a72   u0_a72      20480 2016-05-18 01:30 myapp1.db
-rw------- u0_a72   u0_a72      12824 2016-05-18 01:30 myapp1.db-journal
```

Here is the database class

```
public class DictionaryDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myapp.db";
    private static final String TABLE_DICTIONARY = "dictionary";
    private static final String FIELD_WORD = "word";
    private static final String FIELD_DEFINITION = "definition";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                "(_id integer PRIMARY KEY," +
                FIELD_WORD + " TEXT, " +
                FIELD_DEFINITION + " TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Handle database upgrade as needed
    }

    public void saveRecord(String word, String definition) {
        long id = findWordID(word);
        if (id>0) {
            updateRecord(id, word,definition);
        } else {
            addRecord(word,definition);
        }

    }

    public long addRecord(String word, String definition) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FIELD_WORD, word);
        values.put(FIELD_DEFINITION, definition);
        return db.insert(TABLE_DICTIONARY, null, values);
    }
    public int updateRecord(long id, String word, String definition) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("_id", id);
        values.put(FIELD_WORD, word);
        values.put(FIELD_DEFINITION, definition);
        return db.update(TABLE_DICTIONARY, values, "_id = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }
    public int deleteRecord(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_DICTIONARY, "_id = ?", new
                String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }

    public long findWordID(String word) {
        long returnVal = -1;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                        " WHERE " + FIELD_WORD + " = ?", new String[]{word});
        Log.i("findWordID","getCount()="+cursor.getCount());
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            returnVal = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }


    public String getWord(long id) {
        String returnVal = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT word FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                        " WHERE _id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            returnVal = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }


    public String getDefinition(long id) {
        String returnVal = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT definition FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY +
                        " WHERE _id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            returnVal = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }


    public Cursor getWordList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT _id, " + FIELD_WORD +
                " FROM " + TABLE_DICTIONARY + " ORDER BY " + FIELD_WORD +
                " ASC";
        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
}
```

I have also tried to re-write the class above to comply with the much referenced [tutorial](http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/), but was unsuccessful. 
So really appreciate your help to resolve this problem.

Comment: `I've filled the database and the app works fine on the emulator but when I try to access it on my mobile` what do you meant by creating on emulator and accessing it on mobile ?

Comment: I mean, when I connect my mobile phone to my development machine through usb cable and try to access the app on the mobile.

Comment: what happen then ?

Comment: As I mentioned, the apps comes empty on mobile, as if there is no data inserted into database. Despite the fact that on emulater the inserted data are displayed.

Comment: Try creating the database from the app itself in the mobile instead of pushing it.

Comment: @AyushMaharjan how?

Comment: When you used push command in adb does it show any message?

Comment: @AyushMaharjan yes I get this message back `20465 KB/s (253952 bytes in 0.012s)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be because of an odd design of your "DataBase Adapter" class. I always make my "myDbHelper" class quite small, and have it included in my "__Name of whatever DB I want to work on__DBAdapter" class.

Here is my SQLiteOpenHelper, This class is included in my __DBAdapter class.

```
private static class myDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public myDbHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                      int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "DATABASE_CREATE: version: " + FeedContract.DATABASE_VERSION);
        // create all table(s) for the database.
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_<TABLE NAME>);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Log version upgrade.
        Log.w(LOG_TAG + "DBHelper", "Upgrading from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        // **** Upgrade DB ****
        // This is where you would manually migrate your data from old DB version to new

        // For now, drop old DB table(s)
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_<TABLE NAME>);

        // Create a the new database.
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Then In my ___DBAdapter class I create the SQL commands to create the table(s) that I'm going to use in that database. (along with the insert/update/delete/query commands) This is the approach I teach in my courses and recommend others follow when starting out. It helps in many ways:

- allows you to test (via Integration tests) your "DBAdapter" class easily
- allows you to better partition your code into smaller sections (more manageable) Separating out the SQLLiteOpenHelper from the rest of the operations ON the SQLite DB.
- allows you to use the same API of you "DBAdapter" class as what SQL uses and to what is provided for Content Providers (I 'generally'(there is always exceptions) believe that you should never make a SQL db without wrapping it with a Content Provider)

---

Making the SQLiteOpenHelper class as small as possible helps narrow your code and make it more tractable.

Comment: Sorry, I could not follow. I've copied my db class from the book `Android cookbook`.

Comment: Ohh, that's interesting, because the approach I was discussing was what the Reto Meier Android books suggested, and its what I've used since android 1.0~ish. Edit above incoming

Comment: Can you please rewrite my class with your favorite method, so that I can try it?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicSyncAdapter/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/basicsyncadapter/provider/FeedProvider.java Here is a full working example for you to look at

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your phone is not rooted and you have not actually pushed the database into your phone. You mention that you cannot see path /data/data/com.myappshop.myapp in your file browser.

Comment: Do you mean I need to root my device to be able to push the database to it? I've never heard that.

Comment: Yes, you can access /data folder only when your device is rooted.

Comment: Try this: http://denniskubes.com/2012/09/25/read-android-data-folder-without-rooting/

Comment: Well using `ab shell` I can see the database in the path. please refer to my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the database after it has been installed must be the problem. Try Reinstalling the app